# Perl operators that modify inputs in-place

Tags: perl

I recently took a Perl test and one of the questions was to find all the Perl operations that can be used to modify their inputs in-place. The options were

- [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)
- [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)
- [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)
- [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)
- [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

I don't think any of these can modify the inputs in-place. Am I missing anything here or is the question wrong?

Comment: Can you show some examples of in place modify? https://eval.in/189209

Comment: Thanks slade and tobyink!! mpapec please refer to the answers below.

Comment: Check my link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my @array = qw(1 2 3 4);
print "@array\n";

my @new_array = map ++$_, @array;

print "@new_array\n";
print "@array\n";  # oops, we modified this in-place
```

`grep` is similar. For `sort`, the `$a` and `$b` variables are aliases back to the original array, so can also be used to modify it. The result is somewhat unpredictable, depending on what sorting algorithm Perl is using (which has historically changed in different versions of Perl, though hasn't changed in a while).

```
my @arr = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
my @new = sort { ++$a } @arr;
print "@arr\n";
```

`do` and `eval` can take an arbitrary code block, so can obviously modify any non-readonly variable, though it's not clear whether that counts as modifying inputs in place. Slade's example using the stringy form of `eval` should certainly count though.

Comment: So his test was flawed. No option stating `All of the above`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the question is testing to see if the student knows to properly use the return values of `sort`, `map`, and so on instead of using them in void context and expecting side effects. It's totally possible to modify the parameters given, though.

`map` and `grep` alias `$_` to each element, so modifying `$_` will change the values of the variables in the list passed to it (assuming they're not constants or literals).

`eval EXPR` and `do EXPR` can do anything, more or less, so there's nothing stopping you from doing something like:

```
my $code = q($code = 'modified');
eval $code;
say $code;
```

The arguments to `do BLOCK` and `eval BLOCK` are always a literal block of code, which aren't valid lvalues in any way I know of.

`sort` has a special optimization when called like `@array = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;`. If you look at the opcodes generated by this with B::Concise, you'll see something like:

```
9  <@> sort lK/INPLACE,NUM
```

But for a question about the language semantics, an implementation detail is irrelevant.